# Upload Image via Chromium

Tags: chromium, upload

I want to upload an image via Chromium in a CMS system.

I see this:

[image: upload-image-no-preview]

I don't know the exact name, I would like to see the image before uploading it.

I could open the folder in nautilus, store the exact image name in my brain, and then upload the file with the matching filename. But that's too complicated for me.

How can I enable the preview of the images?

I use Ubuntu 22.04.3